# How to AddOrUpdate from a list without foreach statement?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, ef-code-first, seed

Usually, I go something like this in *Seed()* method.

```
List<Thing> stuff = ...;
foreach(Thing thing in stuff)
  model.Things.AddOrUpdate(thing);
```

Now, I noticed that in the comments, they suggest something like this.

```
context.People.AddOrUpdate(
  p => p.FullName,
  new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
  new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
  new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
);
```

And I'm curious if it only works on explicitly declared, individual instances or if I can hook it up to my *stuff* list?

I've tried the following, which of course didn't work and then, I realized that perhaps I'm barking at the wrong tree to begin with. So before I deliver an excessive amount of barking, I'm asking humbly if it's possible at all.

```
context.Things.AddOrUpdate(_ => _, stuff);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520(v=vs.103).aspx) used in your example have a `params` array as the last parameter.  This means if you provide one of more items then an array will be created that contains those items.

Alternatively, you can just provide an array, so this would work:

```
model.Things.AddOrUpdate(stuff.ToArray());
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/w5zay9db.aspx) for params and included examples might be useful.